# Is there a framework like Twisted Matrix for C#?

Tags: c#, networking, rpc

A few years ago I experimented with TwistedMatrix for Python and loved it.  Unfortunately my current project precludes the use of Python as C# is the only language allowed.

Comment: @Scott M, i think OP mentioned that "C# is the only language allowed". Also it seems that IronPython does not run Twisted anyway: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3882 .

Comment: unfortunately there are technical issues the preclude the use of Python on the client side.  Though on the server side it'd be fine.

Comment: What about signalR https://github.com/signalr would that do what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking for an asynchronous API for sending data, WCF will work fine. Generate the async bindings when creating your endpoint.

The ServiceStack framework is also fairly close, and a little easier than WCF. As you can see in their C# client example, you can easily do async event handlers:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client

Comment: Thanks for that @Brannon.  Say, is this still the way to go, all these years later?  Cheers

Comment: No. This is not the way to go. Enterprise application mostly on LAN? For that I would consider DDS or something built on top of that like ROS2. I would also look at MS's SignalR 3, MS's WebApi stuff on the newer .NET ASP.NET core, and WampSharp. I did quite a few comparisons a year ago. To see that, look for the socket benchmarks here: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/196